# Attatchment is empty when sending blob from azure function

Tags: c#, azure

We have a function that has to send a csv file uploaded to blob storage by email.

The email gets sent, but the csv file is empty on the email, when checking the file on blob storage it has contents.

```
public async Task Run([BlobTrigger("kpfiledumps/{name}", Connection = "AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING")] Stream myBlob, string name, ILogger log)
{
    log.LogInformation($"C# Blob trigger function Processed blob\n Name:{name} \n Size: {myBlob.Length} Bytes");
    
    if (myBlob != null)
    {
        var apiKey = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SENDGRID_KEY");
        var client = new SendGridClient(apiKey);
        var from = new EmailAddress("redacted", "redacted FileFetcher");
        var subject = $"New redacted dump : {name}";
        var to = new EmailAddress("redacted ", "redacted  Files");
        var plainTextContent = "Please see file attatched.";
        var htmlContent = "<strong>Please see file attatched.</strong>";
        var msg = MailHelper.CreateSingleEmail(from, to, subject, plainTextContent, htmlContent);
        await msg.AddAttachmentAsync(name, myBlob); <----This sends an empty csv file
        var response = client.SendEmailAsync(msg).Result;
        log.LogInformation($"Email sent, Response:{response}");
    }
}
```

Is there a specific way to read the stream into a csv file?

Comment: what do you got from the log?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code, you're not doing anything with the blob that triggered your Function. The stream `myBlob` points to the triggering blob, but is never used in your Function.

If I'm not mistaking, adding the attachment should look something like this:

`await msg.AddAttachmentAsync(name, myBlob);`

Please make sure the position of the stream is at the beginning of the file before you attach it to the email message.

Also: have a look at using a [SendGrid binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-sendgrid?tabs=csharp). It enables you to send out an email even faster using an Azure Function, since you will not have to get the API Key or create a client yourself.

Comment: Ahhh sorry about that I had extra logic to try and copy the stream, even using myBlob it seems to still be empty

Comment: Please post the additional code, since it might do something to the stream causing the issue.